# Nested routes in ui-router don't resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm attempting to setup a simple nested view inside of UI-Router, I've done this before yet for some reason this time nested routes do not want to be activated.

My main home.html shows up normally and allows content but any nested views don't appear. I've  checked against my old code and can't find a difference.

In my HTML

The `home.html` is rendered via `ui-view` in the `index.html`

```
# Home.html
<p>Hello World<a ui-sref="hello">
    <button>go hello</button></a>
  <div ui-view></div>
</p>


# Hello.html
<p>Hello HTML</p>
```

And in my app.js for routes I have:

```
angular.module('concierge.customer',
    ['ngCookies',
     'ui.router',
     'restangular'
    ])

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                controller: function() {
                  console.log('Home Base')
                },
                        templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.html'
                })
            .state('home.hello', {
                url: '/hello',
                controller: function() {
                  console.log('Home Hello')
                },
                templateUrl: 'modules/home/hello.html'
            })
    })

    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            console.log("You are going from ", fromState);
            console.log('To: ', toState);
        })
    }])
```

If I type in `/hello` manually to the address bar I get

`Error: Could not resolve 'hello' from state 'home'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a known issue with jade

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/247

Answer (score -1):

In your second .state use only hello, not home.hello, it should help.

Here is plunker where i added two link Ahoy and Hello :

```
plnkr.co/edit/nautvr?p=preview
```

Comment: Maybe i didn`t understand you example good, i have added one more level under go hello. is it that ?